# The functions $f$ and $g$ are not continuous and have directional derivative at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $$f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)=\begin{cases}y^2\log|x|& ,x\neq 0,\\0 &,x=0.\end{cases}$$
and 
$$g:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2 y}{x^2+y^2}& ,(x,y)\neq (0,0),\\\;0 &,x=y=0.\end{cases}$$
I want to show that

1. $f$ and $g$ are not continuous at $(0,0).$
2. $f$ and $g$ have directional derivatives at $(0,0).$

**PART A:**
To show that $f$ and $g$ are not continuous, it suffices to use line, i.e. $y=\alpha x,\;\alpha\in \Bbb{R}$. So, I have

$$f(x,y)=f(x,\alpha x)=\alpha^2 x^2\log|x|$$ which goes to $0$ as $x\to 0$
Also, $$g(x,y)=g(x,\alpha x)=\frac{\alpha x^3 }{x^2+\alpha^2 x^2}=\frac{\alpha x }{1+\alpha^2 \alpha^2}$$ which also goes to $0$ as $x\to 0.$ So, why I'm I not arriving at the desired result? Could my computation be wrong?

**PART B:**
Let $(x_0,y_0)\in \Bbb{R}^2.$ Then, for $x_0\neq 0,$
$$f((x_0,y_0)+(h_1,h_2))-f(x_0,y_0)$$
$$f(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2)-f(x_0,y_0)$$
$$=(y_0+h_2)^2\log|x_0+h_1|-y^2_0 \log|x_0|.$$

I got stuck here. So, could anyone please, help-out? I would be glad for any help rendered.

Comment: What makes you think that those lines suffice?

Comment: @user293794: Elementarily, that's the only thing I can do for now. Don't know how to use other means.

Comment: You need to show the *exists* a path such that $\lim f(p(x),q(x))\ne0$ where $\lim p(x)=\lim q(x)=0$(same for $g$). For example the $(p(x),q(x))=(x,\sqrt{\frac1{\log|x|}})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PART A:** For $f$ consider the sequences $x_n=\exp(-n^2)$ and $y_n=1/n$. Then $(x_n,y_n)\to(0,0)$, but $f(x_n,y_n)=-1\not\to 0=f(0,0)$.

In contrast to $f$ the function $g$ IS actually continuous at $(0,0)$. To see this note that $|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$ and hence $|g(x,y)|\leq|x|$.

**PART B:** First recall the definition of directional derivative: A function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ has a directional derivative at $(x_0,y_0)$ with direction $v=(v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb R^2\backslash\{(0,0)\},||v||=1$, if the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x_0+t v_1,y_0+tv_2)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}
\end{align*} 
exists. (Some authors allow $v$ to be any vector, not necessarily normalized).

To show that $f$ and $g$ have directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ you need to show that the limits $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tv_1,tv_2)}{t}$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(tv_1,tv_2)}{t}$ exist, where $v=(v_1,v_2)$ is a (normalized) vector in $\mathbb R^2$. For $f$ we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(tv_1,tv_2)}{t}=tv_2^2\log|t v_1|\to0\quad\text{ as }t\to0, 
\end{align*}
and for $g$ we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{g(tv_1,tv_2)}{t}=\frac{t^3v_1^2v_2}{t^3(v_1^2+v_2^2)}=v_1^2v_2\quad\text{ for all }t\neq 0.
\end{align*}
Note that since $v=(v_1,v_2)$ has norm 1, we have $1=||v||^2=v_1^2+v_2^2$.

Comment: Please, can you show me how to get those derive those normalized vectors or how they came about? I need it for explanation! Thanks!

Comment: How did you get \begin{align*}
\frac{t^3v_1^2v_2}{t^3(v_1^2+v_2^2)}=v_1^2v_2\quad\text{ for all }t\neq 0.?
\end{align*} I seem not to understand!

Comment: I added a little detail to the answer. If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to ask!